# importing from module after it has been imported in python

Tags: python

I'm curious why the following works:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
```

while the following does not:

```
import pandas as pd
from pd import DataFrame
```

Clearly the interpreter knows that `pd` is a module as evidenced by `type(pd)`. Does it have to do with the fact that `from` is searching for `pd` on the path directly rather than using the alias?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Importing modules assumes a module in `sys.modules` or perhaps even `sys.path`, not a module that you have already imported. There is no `pd` module in `sys.modules` which is why you got an error.

Also even if there is a module with such a name, it is probably not related to `pandas`.